# Java Stored Procedure: OUT params

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I have to make some java procedure in Oracle with 'OUT' parameters. 
Procedure must be like this:

```
create or replace 
procedure SomeProcedure(input1 IN VARCHAR2, result1 OUT VARCHAR2, result2 OUT VARCHAR2)
...
...
```

How do i do that? How i must specify Java class and method? How do I create stored procedure from this class and method?
Any simple examples?

**UPD**: just solve that:

```
create or replace and compile java source named "TestOutParams" as
public class TestOutParams{
    public static void someMethod(String[] value){
        value[0] = "Hello";
    }
};
/

create or replace procedure TestOutParams(value OUT VARCHAR2) as
language java
NAME 'TestOutParams.someMethod(java.lang.String[])';
/

SQL>var value VARCHAR2(40);
SQL>exec TestOutParams(:value);
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
SQL>PRINT value;
VALUE
---------

Hello
```

I dont know, why, but its working!

Comment: @Augusto don't be angry. I solved that issue.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's something like this;

```
CallableStatement stmt = null;
stmt = conn.prepareCall("begin SomeProcedure(?,?,?); end;");
stmt.setString(1, new String("value1"));             // Bind 1st input parameter
stmt.setString(2, new String("value2"));          // Bind 2nd input parameter
stmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);     // 3rd parameter is OUT
stmt.execute();

String retcod = new String(stmt.getInt(3));
```

Comment: He wants to expose a java function.